# why require() is checked after executing transfer()

Tags: contract-design, erc-721, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

From OpenZeppelin's ERC721 contract:

```
    function _safeTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory _data) internal virtual {
        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
        require(_checkOnERC721Received(from, to, tokenId, _data), "ERC721: transfer to non ERC721Receiver implementer");
    }
```

In the above code, what purpose does `require(...)` server after `_transfer()` as the token will be transferred anyways? I would like to details regarding why such an approach is used.

Moreover, if `to` is a contract, `_checkOnERC721Received` returns true always. what does this signify? Is any ethereum contract compatible to hold ERC721 safely out-of-the-box, even without implement `ERC721Receiver` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) suggests an optional interface named `ERC721TokenReceiver` :

```
/// @dev Note: the ERC-165 identifier for this interface is 0x150b7a02.
interface ERC721TokenReceiver {
/// @notice Handle the receipt of an NFT
/// @dev The ERC721 smart contract calls this function on the recipient
///  after a `transfer`. This function MAY throw to revert and reject the
///  transfer. Return of other than the magic value MUST result in the
///  transaction being reverted.
///  Note: the contract address is always the message sender.
/// @param _operator The address which called `safeTransferFrom` function
/// @param _from The address which previously owned the token
/// @param _tokenId The NFT identifier which is being transferred
/// @param _data Additional data with no specified format
/// @return `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`
///  unless throwing
function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes _data) external returns(bytes4);
}
```

This interface has only one function named `onERC721Received` which returns a constant value equal to `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`.
You can find an exemple of implementation here : https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/utils/ERC721Holder.sol.

### What's the purpose of this interface ?

If someone sends tokens to a smart contract not supporting the ERC721 standard, the NFT could be lost forever.

The EIP-721 implements a `safeTransferFrom` function to prevent such a bad situation. This method does basically the same thing that `transferFrom`, except it calls a private function named `_checkOnERC721Received` at the end of the execution.

### How does `_checkOnERC721Received` work ?

`_checkOnERC721Received` has the following behavior :

1. if the receiving address `to` is an EOA, it returns true
2. if the receiving address `to` is a smart contract, it will call on the contract the `onERC721Received` method seen above and check the result :

- if the contract returns the magic value, `_checkOnERC721Received` returns true
- else it returns false and the `_safeTransfer` call fails (as the `require` condition is not met).

### Why does `_checkOnERC721Received` is called at the end ?

To respect the Checks-Effects-Interactions pattern and prevent reentrancy attacks : `_safeTransfer` first update the ERC721 contract states, then it calls the external smart contract.

Comment: thanks, @clement but this does not answer my question that why `require` is called later after sending `_trasfer` and how does it differ if `require` is called before `transfer`

Comment: @hack3r_0m Check the last point of my answer : inside the `require` statement there is a  potential call to an external smart contract; this is good practice to call external contracts at the end after updating the calling contract state. This is a security measure to prevent attacks such as reentrancy.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, a transaction will revert unless all conditions are successfully met. In this example, it means that you can perform the `_transfer()` successfully, but if the `require` afterwards fails, the whole transaction will be reverted (including the previous transfer).

Once said that, this `require` is checking whether the destination address is a contract:

- If not, it will return true and transfer will be done.
- If it is a contract, it will check whether the contract is compatible with the ERC721 standard. If it is compatible, it will return true; otherwise, it will return false and the transaction will be reverted in order to avoid sending ERC721 tokens to a non ERC721-compatible contract (equivalent to burning such as tokens).

Comment: so what is the scope of require() if statements executed above it can also be reverted? thanks for correct on the smart contract part :) I didn't not `!` while reading code.

Comment: It's a good point. I normally put all requires at the beginning of a function to do an early revert if any condition is not met -> this way, the gas consumed will be lower as compared to executing unnecessary statements that can be reverted afterwards. There is probably a good reason for doing this, but you may ask at OpenZeppelin's forum.